# Событие Activity Lifecicle при закрытии DialoFragment

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Есть `Activity`, с него вызываю `DialogFragment`. `DialogFragment` закрывается, как дать понять `Activity` что `DialogFragment`только что закрылся? Сразу на ум приходит `OnResume`, но как оказалось он не вызывается при `dismiss()` диалога. Какой метод вызывается в `Activity` при закрытии диалога что-бы его можно было переопределить и засунуть туда свой код.

Comment: Что мешает добавить этот код в кнопку закрытия диалога?

Comment: Нужно что-бы этот код обновлял листвью. А если добавить в код закрытия, то оно не обновляет.